# Can't use HMACSHA1 class in C++

Tags: cryptography, c++-cli, hmacsha1

I am trying to follow [this sample code for C++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hmacsha1(v=vs.110).aspx), but the line:

```
Using namespace System::Security::Cryptography;
```

throws an error in VS 2013 pro.  The word System is underlined in red and the mouse-over message says: "name followed by '::' must be a class or namespace name".  I have working code using the HMACSHA1 class in several languages (C#, VB.net, python, etc) but can't get it working in C++.  What is the problem with accessing this class in C++?  Should I be using a different namespace, or adding an #include for some file?  I have seen an [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382379(v=vs.85).aspx) of using the HMAC class in C, but that is an "abstract class" and appears that it would require a lot more work to get what I want.  I don't understand why I can't use the HMACSHA1 class which delivers exactly what I need.

(Just in case someone asks, my working vb.net code looks like this:

```
Private Function GetApi_Sig()
    Dim api_sig As String = ""
    Using myhmac As New HMACSHA1(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secret))
        Dim hashValue As Byte() = myhmac.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key))
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To (hashValue.Length - 1)
            api_sig = api_sig + String.Format("{0:x2}", hashValue(i))
        Next i
    End Using
    Return api_sig
End Function 'GetApi_Sig
```

)

Comment: Forgive the obvious question: Your C++ project is setup for CLI, *right* ?

Comment: sorry, i don't know what CLI means, maybe that is the issue.  can you elaborate?

Comment: Is your C++ project configured as a .NET project? C++ and .NET play by their own set of language rules, if you weren't aware. Worth looking in to if that is the case.

Comment: I started new project in VS, it is a win32 console app with .net framework 4.5 selected in the dropdown.  does that mean it is configured as a .NET project?

Comment: OK, so when starting project, I picked the CLR node under C++ and then picked CLR Console app... and now the noted error is gone... so on to coding to see if I can get this to work.  thanks whozCraig.

Comment: Now you've got it working: your secret should not be a password (consist only of printable characters). You should at least make sure that your password is strong enough (but you're still missing a salt and iteration count compared to e.g. PBKDF2).